# JSON not parsing from a Discord message

Tags: json, typescript, discord.js

Coding a discordv13 bot with TypeScript and I want a feature where you can create a custom embed in a channel by sending JSON that gets parsed by the bot.

Here is the code:

```
import { ICommand } from 'wokcommands';
import { MessageEmbed } from 'discord.js';

export default {
    category: 'Embeds',
    description: 'Creates a custom embed with JSON',
    aliases: ['newembed', 'embedcreate'],

    callback: ({ text }) => {
        const json = JSON.parse(text)

        const jsonEmbed = new MessageEmbed(json)

        return jsonEmbed
    }
} as ICommand
```

I am using an npm package called WOKCommands which is just an advanced command handler.

When I send the message in Discord, the bot does not respond and I get an error in my console that says:

```
                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 7
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

FYI the message I sent in Discord was `"!createembed "title": "Hello world", "description": "hello world"`

Please advise.

Comment: `"!createembed "title": "Hello world", "description": "hello world"` is not valid JSON, so you can't use a JSON parser to process it.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`working with JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!createembed {"title": "Hello world", "description": "hello world"}` might work. To have multiple values in JSON you need to create an *Object* (`{}`)